# MySQL JOIN Many tables to get a list of criteria into one table

Tags: php, mysql, join, where-clause

I am trying to figure out how to use ONE table JOIN to get a list of vehicle MAKE, MODEL, YEAR, and TRIMS criteria, available for the customer to search from.

There are already **master key** tables, from which the admin selects from a range of vehicle options and enters these vehicle related details about that product to the **PRODUCT** table.

I want to now produce a list for the shopper, that reflects only the available vehicle details choices - based on what has been entered into the **PRODUCTS** table by the admin.

I have been looping / iterating over the MAKE MODEL TRIMS tables with PHP and searching the PRODUCTS table for the existence of the MAKE MODEL YEAR TRIM type in the table of **PRODUCTS**. But it is taking about 800 individual calls to the PRODUCTS table.

It is understood that this is **not** the best practice and could cause all sorts of problems - being way to many calls to the database and not efficient.

I am told in another question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960571/sanity-check-mysql-whats-reasonable-800-calls-to-the-database-in-one-second

that this can be done with one call using **JOIN** and **WHERE** statements.

I have used table JOINS before, but do not see how this could be done with one call on these many MAKES, MODELS, YEARS, TRIMS to produce one list of available MAKES, MODELS, YEARS, TRIMS criteria for the shopper to choose from.

I would appreciate anything I can learn about this here from your examples : )

**Here is an example of the admin master key selection tables for adding vehicle related details to the product entry record:**

---

Table: **MAKES**

```
| Id | MAKE      | // Admin table for selecting products related vehicle make 
------------------
| 1  | FORD      |
| 2  | CHEV      |
| 3  | GMC       |
| 4  | HONDA     |
etc.
```

Table: **FORD**

```
| Id | MODEL     | // Admin table for selecting products related vehicle model 
------------------
| 1  | F150      |
| 2  | ESCAPE    |
| 2  | EXPLORER  |
etc.
```

Table: **FORD_F150_YEARS_TRIMS**

```
| Id | YEARS|                  TRIMS                      |  // Admin table for selecting products related vehicle year and trim(s)
--------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1999 | 1999_SPORT+1999_SPORTRAC+1999_XLT+1999_XLS  |
| 2  | 2000 | 2000_XLT+2000_XLS+2000_LTD+2000_EDDIE_BAUER |
| 3  | 2001 | 2001_SPORTRAC+2001_XLT+2001_LTD             |
etc.
```

---

**Here is the products table that the admin is entering the product / vehicle details:**

Table: **PRODUCTS**

```
| PRODUCT_ID  | MAKE          |          MODELS         |      YEARS       |                                     TRIMS                                               |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 123456      | FORD FORD GMC |   F150 ESCAPE CANYON    |  2000 2001 1999  | FORD_F150_1999_SPORT+FORD_F150_1999_SPORTRAC+GMC_CANYON_1999_LTD+GMC_CANYON_1999_LTD    |
| 123457      | FORD GMC CHEV | F150 EXPLORER SILVERADO |  2000 2010 2010  | FORD_F150_2001_XLT+FORD_F150_2001_LTD+GMC_CANYON_2010_XLT+CHEV_SILVERADO_1500_2010_LTD  |
etc.
```

What I want to do is - make a query on the **PRODUCTS** table where I can produce a table or list of only the **vehicle types** that there are products for.

So, if there is **NOT** a product in the **PRODUCTS** table that fits a **2001 FORD F150** with a **SPORTRAC** trim - then I do not want to give the shopper the choice of **SPORTRAC** with **2001 FORD F150** but I do want to give them the choice of **2001 FORD F150** with **XLT** + **LTD**

So really - I just want to eliminate choices for the shopper for products vehicle details that don't exist.

I am told that this can be done in one MySQL call to the database. I am told that instead of looping through all the **makes, models** and **trims** and making individual calls to the PRODUCTS table - I can somehow use table joins and while statements to get a list of all the potential **MAKE MODEL TRIMS** choices available for the customer based on what is in the PRODUCTS table only

I see how I could do this by making one call to the PRODUCTS table and then looping through and weeding out duplicates on the result with PHP. But there are thousands of products and these could gro - so I am looking for the best practice method of achieving this.

Comment: Hmm...You tables have no foreign keys? Are you sure that is the whole structure for tables Makes, Ford and FORD_F150_YEARS_TRIMS? Do you have a table for each brand? a Ford table, a Honda table, etc?

Comment: Mike Brant's answer is very good.  I had assumed in the initial question that this would be the type of schema you were working with.

Comment: Hi Mickle - yeas, there is a Ford Table and a Honda table and a Chev table and so on. Each contains the years and trims that a product could be possibly created for.

Comment: It would be a lot simpler if you normalise your data.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems you first and foremost problem is that you have these different tables but you are not using them in a relational manner.  You should really spend some time learning about how to properly normalize your tables.  As a general guideline, you should really think about how real world items/properties that you are related to one another and express that relationship through proper primary and foreign key usage.

Your products should relate to the makes, models, trims, etc. via the various primary key id's, not by duplicating the data in the products tables.  You also shouldn't have a 'Ford' table for example, but rather just a table with of 'models'.

Just as a sample, I might have a schema like this

```
models
---------
model_id
make_id
model

makes (Make is really just a property of the model of car, and could possibly be de-normalized into models table. Here I am showing it as separate table to show a fully normalized example.)
---------
make_id
make

trims ('SPORT+XLS' unless those represent a specific trim combination.  Each different trim package should have its own row)
--------
trim_id
trim

products (I am assuming that a model and year define a product, by looking at your example data)
--------
product_id
year
model_id


product_trims (many-to-many table expressing relation of products to trims - you could have multiple rows with same product_id and different trim id)
-------------
product_id
trim_id
```

If you really want to have a product defined as a combination of year, model, and trim, you could eliminate the product_trims table and just have a revised product table like this

```
product
-------------
product_id
year
model_id
trim_id
```

You could then query across joins to get the data you need.  For example, let's say the user has specified a model and a year.  The query might look like the following (showed assuming use of both products and products_trim tables)

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.year, ma.make, mo.model, t.trim
FROM
products AS p
INNER JOIN models AS mo ON p.model_id = mo.model_id
INNER JOIN makes AS ma ON mo.make_id = ma.make_id
INNER JOIN product_trims AS pt ON p.product_id = pt.product_id
INNER JOIN trims AS t ON pt.trim_id = t.trim_id
WHERE p.year = '?' AND p.model_id = ?
```

Of course, you need to properly index all the filed used for joins and for any WHERE or ORDER BY conditions.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to reply - I was with you up to the separation of the product_trims into product_id and trim_id. I think I messed up my table example - sorry. There is actually potentially many-to-many relationship for each PRODUCT as each PRODUCT can have multiple MAKES, and MODELS, AND TRIMS. I'll revise my table examples - but I think I see where you are going. I should have a TRIMS/product_id and a Models/Product_id table etc that utilize primary key id's.

Comment: I learned relational database - believe it or not - and table joins. But have trouble seeing how to JOIN multiple tables. And I do understand what you are saying about foreign and primary keys etc. I think I am making a mistake of using the variable values as javascript values, then also HTML values. It seemed to make sense to use 'FORD' and 'F150' as primary key values, and then write those into javascript values with the PHP, and then write those javascript values as HTML 'id' values and text values for the human to view. I know, I'm crazy, but it seemed to be less calls to the DB that way.